# not be able to retrieve firebase data using addValueEventListener

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to retrieve firebase data using addValueEventListener, but unfortunately i am not be able to get right data. 
I have New_Deal_List.java class, and in this class i want to retrieve `public class New_Deal_List extends AppCompatActivity {

```
ListView lvDealList;

List<NewDeal_Database> dealList;

DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Expert");

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.new__deal__list);

    lvDealList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lvDealList);
    dealList = new ArrayList<>();
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    rootRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            dealList.clear();
            for(DataSnapshot dealSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){

                NewDeal_Database info = dealSnapshot.getValue(NewDeal_Database.class);
                dealList.add(info);
            }

            DealList adapter = new DealList( New_Deal_List.this,dealList);
            lvDealList.setAdapter(adapter);
        }


        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Toast.makeText(New_Deal_List.this,"Databse error",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });
}
```

I am adding data through  New_Deal.java by this method

```
private void AddNewDeal(){
    int DealName = Integer.parseInt(etDealName.getText().toString());
    String NewDealCategory = etNewDealCategory.getText().toString();
    String DishName = etDishName.getText().toString();
    String DealDescription  = etDealDescription.getText().toString();

    if(TextUtils.isEmpty(etDishName.getText().toString()) || TextUtils.isEmpty(etNewDealCategory.getText().toString()) || TextUtils.isEmpty(etDishName.getText().toString()) || TextUtils.isEmpty(etDealDescription.getText().toString())){
        Toast.makeText(this,"All fileds must be filled.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }else{
        DealId = keyRefrence.push().getKey();
        //firebaseDatabase data =  new firebaseDatabase(DealName,NewDealCategory,DishName,DealDescription);

        //Contact_Info info = new Contact_Info( DealName, NewDealCategory,  DealDescription);
        NewDeal_Database info =  new NewDeal_Database(DealName,NewDealCategory, DishName,  DealDescription);      keyRefrence.child(Cooker_Deal).child(DealId).child(Deal).setValue(info);

        Toast.makeText(this,"Information Added",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Intent intent = new Intent(New_Deal.this,New_Deal_Time.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

I am setting value using this NewDeal_Databse.java

```
public NewDeal_Database(int DealName,String NewDealCategory, String DishName, String DealDescription){
    this.DealName = DealName;
    this.NewDealCategory = NewDealCategory;
    this.DishName = DishName;
    this.DealDescription = DealDescription;
}


public int getDealName() {
    return DealName;
}

public String getNewDealCategory() {
    return NewDealCategory;
}

public String getDishName() {
    return DishName;
}

public String getDealDescription() {
    return DealDescription;
}
```

Also i DealList.java for array adapter

```
public class DealList  extends ArrayAdapter <NewDeal_Database> {

    private Activity context;
    private List<NewDeal_Database> dealList;

    public DealList(Activity context, List<NewDeal_Database> dealList){
        super(context, R.layout.list_layout, dealList);
        this.context = context;
        this.dealList = dealList;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater =  context.getLayoutInflater();

        View listViewItem = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_layout,null,true);

        TextView tvDealName = (TextView)listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.tvDealNamelayout);
        TextView tvNewDealCategory = (TextView)listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.tvNewDealCategorylayout);
        NewDeal_Database info = dealList.get(position);

        tvDealName.setText(String.valueOf(info.getDealName()));
        tvNewDealCategory.setText(info.getNewDealCategory());

        return listViewItem;
    }
}
```

I get these on values on output

[Output the data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iaDM8.png)

I this is firebase databse snapshot

[firebase datasbe snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h6828.png)

[updated firebase databse snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xflND.png)

[Updated output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/stPTr.png)

Problem solved using this code:

```
    @Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();


    //dealList.clear();

    rootRef.child(id).child(Cooker_Deal).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {


            for(DataSnapshot dealSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                for(DataSnapshot datas : dealSnapshot.getChildren()){       //
                    NewDeal_Database info = datas.getValue(NewDeal_Database.class);
                    count++;
                    if(count>3){
                        dealList.add(info);
                        count=0;
                    }


                }
            }
            DealList adapter = new DealList( New_Deal_List.this,dealList);
            lvDealList.setAdapter(adapter);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
```

Comment: You want to get the data under Deals Information? Do you have the expertId?

Comment: No i want data under New_Deal_List.java class, and yes I have expertId.

Comment: Under New_Deal_List.java class are 4 fields. You need those values (DealName, NewDealCategory, DishName,DealDescription) of a particular expert, it's correct?

Comment: I want to show DealName and NewDealCategory on listview of particular expert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think its nested too much but to answer your question, you need to remove this from your code:

```
  dealList.clear();
```

and add it outside of the `addValueEventListener()`

like this:

```
protected void onStart() {
super.onStart();
   dealList.clear();
rootRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
```

Edit:

```
  @Override
 protected void onStart() {
super.onStart();
  dealList.clear();
rootRef.child(expertId).child("Cooker Deals").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        for(DataSnapshot dealSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
         for(DataSnapshot datas : dealSnapshot.getChildren(){
             NewDeal_Database info = datas.getValue(NewDeal_Database.class);
            dealList.add(info);



        }

        DealList adapter = new DealList( New_Deal_List.this,dealList);
        lvDealList.setAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.notifydatasetchanged();
    }
```

Comment: Nothing changed. Same output.

Comment: you want dealdescription, dealname..?

Comment: I want DealName and NewDealCategory.

Comment: I get this error.  com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Can't convert object of type java.lang.String to type com.faum.faum_expert.NewDeal_Database. at this line NewDeal_Database info = datas.getValue(NewDeal_Database.class);

Comment: try it now @ArsalanSaleem

Comment: I don't have enough reputation for chat.

Comment: @ArsalanSaleem no need to chat, try the updated now. I just updated it now

Comment: i get the output. But one problem i get extra empty lines of listview. See updated output and updated firebase snapshots. Thanks @PeterHaddad

Comment: Can you please help me to remove extra lines from listview? Yes sure.

Comment: still same output.

Comment: Still same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `faum-expert` nide is a direct child of your Firebase database, to get that data, please use the following code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference ref = rootRef.child("faum-expert").child("Expert").child(expertId).child("Cooker Deals");
ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String dealName = ds.child("Deals Information").child("dealName").getValue(String.class);
            String newDealCategory = ds.child("Deals Information").child("newDealCategory").getValue(String.class);
            Log.d("TAG", dealName + " / " + newDealCategory);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
```

The output will be:

```
4567 / kagj
```

But pay atention, the fields inside your model class are first letter uppercase and in your database are first letter lowercase. To solve this, add the following annotations in front of your fields like this:

```
@PropertyName("dealName")
private String DealName;
@PropertyName("newDealCategory")
private String NewDealCategory;
@PropertyName("dishName")
private String DishName;
@PropertyName("dealDescription")
private String DealDescription;
```

Comment: I changed the code as you said. Also first letter to lowercase, but I get blank screen output. Like empty screen with no values.

Comment: Can you share the new code and add a screenshot of your database including the firebase root.

Comment: Is faum-expert a direct child of your Firebase database root?

Comment: DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Expert"); thats my root refrence.

Comment: That is wrong. That's why was not working. You did not used my code. It should be getReference() without an argument.

Comment: Oh sorry i used this. DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    DatabaseReference ref = rootRef.child("faum-expert").child("Expert").child(id).child("Cooker Deals");